# Maven Googlewebtoolkit2 plugin: only compile if necessary

Tags: maven, compilation

As compiling the GWT stuff is quite expensive (time consuming) I would like to only have it executed if really necessary (meaning source change, artifact version change, class files missing etc.).
I already work with a profile which is deactivated by default and then one can explicitly activate it by setting the profile.

```
mvn install -DmyProfile
```

The problem is that sometimes the manual activation gets forgotten so I would like to have some kind of automatic detection mechanism. So by executing

```
mvn install
```

the Maven build should automatically compile the GWT stuff if necessary.
Is there a possibility to do so?